# модальное окно после нажатия на кнопку Купить

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

помогите пожалуйста.
есть форма на стр. checkout в Wordpress
как сделать чтоб после нажатия на кнопку Купить,
форма отправлялась и открывалось модальное окно?
типа двойной клик

```
    <?php if ( eb_get_option('payment_method')['arrive-button'] ) : ?>
<div id="checkout_payment_arrive_tab">
<p class="checkout-mssg"><?php echo do_shortcode(eb_get_option('arrive_mssg')) ?></p>
<form action="<?php echo checkout_page() ?>" method="post">
бла бла поля формы
<button type="submit" class="btn eb-btn btn-arrive"> <?php echo esc_html__('Купить', 'arrive-button') ?></button>
</form>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="<?php echo checkout_page() ?>" method="post">
```

в эту строчку добавляем onsubmit

```
<form action="<?php echo checkout_page() ?>" method="post" onsubmit="window.open('URL', '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=320,width=300,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');return true;">
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]